# How to increase the horizontal chart value text size in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), I want to set the barchart values in center of the bar and with bigger font.

```
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
```

By using the above the value is shown inside the bar but not at the center.I am using MpChart 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, it is **not possible to center the values**, you will have to add that feature yourself.

Concerning the textsize, try:
`barDataSet.setValueTextSize(...)`

- [Styling individual DataSets](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-DataSet-class)
- [Styling all ChartData](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ChartData-class)

Comment: Hi
Can you please tell me how to resize the bars in graph?
I am using Another Bar Chart option in your sample MPAndroidChart Example.

Comment: Tried this `barDataSet.setValueTextSize(...)` but not effecting. Any update on this?