# How to increase size of text value on top of MPAndroid Bar Chart?

Tags: text, charts, bar-chart

I have created a chart using MPAndroid Chart. I want to know how can I increase the size of text value on top of each bar in MPAndroid Bar Chart? Which API should I use? I have circled the value in the attached picture in Red circle

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236069/how-to-increase-horizontal-chart-value-text-size-in-mpchart basically,this function
dataSet.setValueTextSize( int );

Answer (score 7):

you can try it by using

```
barDataset.setValueTextSize(12f);
```

where `barDataset` is `BarDataSet`

Comment: Tried this `barDataSet.setValueTextSize(...)` but not effecting. Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to my question after some trials. This is the code to set the font size of left and right Y-axis on a MPAndroidChart

```
    import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart;

 //Code snippet



      CombinedChart combinedChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
      YAxis yaLeft = combinedChart.getAxisLeft();
      YAxis yaRight = combinedChart.getAxisRight();
      yaLeft.setTextSize(14/*textSize*/);
      yaRight.setTextSize(14/*textSize*/);
```